# read_fwf in pandas in Python does not use comment character if colspecs argument does not include first column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When reading fixed-width files using the `read_fwf` function in pandas (0.18.1) with Python (3.4.3), it is possible to specify a comment character using the `comment` argument. I expected that all lines beginning with the comment character would be ignored. However, if you do not specify the first column in the file in any column in `colspecs`, the comment character does not appear to be used.

```
import io, sys
import pandas as pd

sys.version
# '3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]'
pd.__version__
# '0.18.1'

# Two input files, first line is comment, second line is data.
# Second file has a column (with the letter A) 
# that I don't want at start of data.
string = "#\n1K\n"
off_string = "#\nA1K\n"

# When using skiprows to skip commented row, both work.
pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(string), colspecs = [(0,1), (1,2)], skiprows = 1, header = None)
#    0  1
# 0  1  K

pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(off_string), colspecs = [(1,2), (2,3)], skiprows = 1, header = None)
#    0  1
# 0  1  K

# If a comment character is specified, it only works when the colspecs 
# includes the column with the comment character.
pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(string), colspecs = [(0,1), (1,2)], comment = '#', header = None)
#    0  1
# 0  1  K

pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(off_string), colspecs = [(1,2), (2,3)], comment = '#', header = None)
#      0    1
# 0  NaN  NaN
# 1  1.0    K
```

Is there any documentation specifically referring to this? The simple workaround is to include the first column and then remove it after, but I wanted to verify if this was a bug or my misunderstanding the expected behaviour.

Comment: The documentation for the comment flag is here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#comments-and-empty-lines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a bug, the spec in the documentation says "if the line starts with a comment then the entire line is skipped". The problem is that columns are subsetted by `FixedWidthReader.__next__` before they are checked for comments (in `PythonParser` or `CParserWrapper`). The relevant code is in `io/parsers.py`.

Comment: Hm, I thought so. [I reported it on Github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/14135), if they confirm, then I will accept this answer.